# Binary to Decimal using recursion Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, binary, decimal

I have an assignment to create a function that converts binary to decimal in Haskell. It has to be a recursive function that only uses if-then-else,+,times etc. I cannot import a library to simplify the work. I am so far lost any sort of guidance would be helpful I am not familiar with haskell I would be able to do this assignment in another language.

Comment: ok - can you describe the algorithm in words? Maybe we can help you out starting from there

Comment: "I would be able to do this assignment in another language." If you can do it in another language with recursion and without mutation, there is a good chance you can translate it almost verbatim to Haskell.

Comment: Assuming the binary is stored as a list of boolean values, you have 2 cases for your function: (a) the list is empty and you can return 0. (b) the list is not empty. then you have a head value and the rest of the list. For the rest of the list just call the same function. So now given the head value (true/false) and the tail value (a number) you can compute the value for head:tail. This is missing some info on purpose as I don't want to do the assignment for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you could do it in another language, then I would suspect that you would accomplish this by building up the decimal value by adding values to it as you iterate through the bits. Say `2 + 8 + 128` for `10001010`.

In Haskell, you can achieve this with a function with two parameters like so:

```
binary2Decimal decimal [] = decimal
binary2Decimal decimal (bit : binary) = ...
```

What happens is you initially apply `f` to a `decimal` that is `0`, and as you take elements off the head of the list of bits (`binary`), you add a certain decimal value (exercise for the reader) to the current decimal value. When `binary` is `[]`, you have reached the base case and `decimal` will contain the final value.

If you are interested, you can also solve problems of this pattern with a [fold(l/r)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr), which lets you avoid the explicit recursion.

Comment: surely it's not a good idea to first define `fold` to then use it - IMO for beginners it's way easier to define the function using recursion directly - the generalization to `fold`s can follow later (with experience and lot's of the involved patterns seen)

Comment: Good point. I think I instantly recognised a fold in there, and couldn't get it out of my head. I will edit the answer.